# Pressing an asp.net mvc Ajax.ActionLink with Insert into RenderBody() causes an endless loop

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery, actionlink

I have these ActionLinks in my Main Index View:

```
<p>@Ajax.ActionLink("Releases", "Index", "Release", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ContentPanel" })</p>
<p>@Ajax.ActionLink("Templates", "Index", "Template", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ContentPanel" })</p>
<p>@Ajax.ActionLink("Testplans", "Index", "Testplan", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ContentPanel" })</p>
```

below is this:

```
<div id="ContentPanel">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

When I click each link Release,Templates, Testplans one after the other the switching of the views work.

When I click in this order:

```
Releases
Templates
Releases
Templates
```

The switching does not work anymore. The problem seems to be that when I set a breakpoint in my controller index method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

The Index Action is called in a looooooop ??

Why this?

Comment: The problem seems to be the @RenderBody(). I do not need it, but I must use it as a asp.net mvc constraint. And in the Ajax.ActionLink I have to set an AjaxOptions... so one of them I must remove but then the functionality is broken.

Comment: Do You use layout refrence in your view? like this Layout="/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

Comment: yes thats in my _ViewStart.cshtml file defined.

Comment: Could you try this code Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

Comment: YES that helped! seems like a stupid workaround ;-) A last problem is there: In my MainController Index action method I return a View which is useless or the view is never visible. That means the Index action method is just useless code because my visible view is determined by the ActionLinks which one ActionLink will later be invoke from javascript code (First ActionLInk will be activated...) But the asp.net mvc design works that way that there must be an initial controller action call... Any solution to this?

Comment: @AliRiza put your comment in a solution/answer so I can mark it as solved :) the problem I still have will be for a new question :)

Comment: @AliRiza if you are interested ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235554/hmtl-not-correct-rendered-and-no-viewbag-title-is-set-using-ajax-actionlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this code:

```
Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```